# Disable clang-tidy warning for a specific macro

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I have a macro which instantiates a global variable. And thus clang-tidy will correctly issue an "Initialization of ... with static storage duration may throw an exception which cannot be caught".

Can I disable this warning on a per-macro basis? Preferable inline where the macro is defined.

That is, let's say I have:

```
// header.h
#define UGLY_MACRO(X)  SomeClass X(#X)

// source.cpp
UGLY_MACRO(SomeName); // clang-tidy complains here
```

And I want clang-tidy to stop complaining about this.

I want to be as specific as possible. 
I only want to turn of *this* warning for *this* macro. I do not want to turn of the warning globally, then someone might add more of this kind of macros into the code unnoticed.
Also, I don’t want to add something (like a //NOLNT(...)) at every place where the macro is used, that would be too much of a hassle.

Or am I approaching this from the wrong direction? I have worked with pc-lint before, where this is possible.

Comment: Did you try making the `SomeClass` constructor `noexcept`? what happens then?

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem. I have found two ways to do this, none of which are perfect, sadly.

**Option 1** by using the `--line-filter` command-line argument for `clang-tidy`:

```
clang-tidy --line-filter='["name":"header.h"]' source.cpp
```

Notes:

- Sadly this doesn't selectively work on one warning only, it disables all of them.
- Unlike `--filter-regex`, this works even for macro expansion.
- You can be more specific and specify the range of line numbers in `header.h` you want to disable the warnings for (see the help text for `--line-filter`)

**Option 2** by wrapping the macro:

```
#define UGLY_MACRO_NOLINT(...) UGLY_MACRO(__VA_ARGS__) //NOLINT(...)
```

Notes:

- Requires modifying your source code to use the nolint version
- Does not work if `UGLY_MACRO` is multi-line

Comment: In option 2 is the "comment" ("// ... ") really stored as part of the macro, or is a comment that is ignored in the first place?

Comment: I'm no expert, but according to the standard (for both C and C++), comments are removed during translation phase 3, and macros expanded in phase 4. That would mean the comments in general are never "part" of any macro. I suspect though that clang-tidy has an extra pass to identify such comments that are meant to affect its behaviour.

Comment: ok, so, in conclusion, is not completely useless to try to add NOLINT suppression in macro definitions that would act on its expansion later on? Clang tidy could, if it wants, have different rules than C++ preprocessor.

Comment: No, it's not useless; indeed, that is the second solution presented in my answer. It does come with its own drawbacks, as explained.

Comment: Thanks, actually, I just tried and if you put the `NOLINT` in c-style comments `/* NOLINT ... */` you can make it work in multiline macros.

Comment: Oh, really? That's really helpful, thanks! I would appreciate it if you could edit my answer or perhaps add your own, showing exactly how that works.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. The check in question ([cert-err58-cpp](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cert-err58-cpp.html)) doesn't have configurable options which means it can't be disabled on a per-macro basis, only globally.

Save for modifying the check's source the only option you have here is `// NOLINT(cert-err58-cpp)` and `// NOLINTNEXTLINE(cert-err58-cpp)`. The latter is a little easier to use for text search and replace as you only need to catch a newline followed by the macro name.